# Choosing randomly between two objects based on the results of choosing randomly between to two objects

Tags: objective-c

Ok so this is the code I have so far:

```
    x = arc4random_uniform(4);
    if (x <= 1){
        LabelA.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];
    } else {
        LabelA.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"];
    }


{
    x = arc4random_uniform(12);
    if (x <= 3){
        LabelB.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"3"];
    } else {
        LabelB.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"4"];
    }
}
```

Ok so what this will do is choose 1 or 2 randomly and then 3 or 4 randomly. So say it chooses 1 and 3. I then want it to randomly choose between 1 and 3. And if it does choose 1 and 3 I want it to choose 1 20% of the time, but if it chooses 2 and 3 I want it to choose 2 70% of the time. So for each matchup it would be:

- 1 and 3: Choose 1 20% of the time
- 1 and 4: Choose 1 60% of the time
- 2 and 3: Choose 2 70% of the time
- 2 and 4: Choose 2 30% of the time

And then whatever number it chooses I want that to be LabelC. So I'm basically trying to figure out how to code this. I hope this makes sense and you know what I'm trying to do, but any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: FYI - get rid of the needless `stringWithFormat:` calls. Just do `LabelA.text = @"1";`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have variables x (being 1 or 2) and y (being 3 or 4), you can get the odds you want like so,

```
int z;
if (x==1 && y==3) {
    z= (arc4random_uniform(10) < 2)? 1:3;

}else if (x==1 && y==4) {
    z= (arc4random_uniform(10) < 6)? 1:4;

}else if (x==2 && y==3) {
    z= (arc4random_uniform(10) < 7)? 2:3;

}else if (x==2 && y==4) {
    z= (arc4random_uniform(10) < 3)? 2:4;
```

Comment: Oh ok this make sense, but how would I make LabelC be either 1,2,3, or 4?

Comment: @bchesney, Unlike in your question where you had strings, and so didn't need to use stringWithFormat:, here we have an int (z), so you do need to use stringWithFormat: to create a string for the label. labelC.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", z];

Answer (score 0):

A version with less `if` statements...

```
int a[][3] = {{1,3,2},{1,4,6},{2,3,7},{2,4,3}};

int rand1 = arc4random_uniform(2);
int rand2 = arc4random_uniform(12);
int index = rand1 * 2 + rand2 > 3;

int b = (arc4random_uniform(10)<a[index][2] ? a[index][0] : a[index][1]);
LabelA.text = @(a[index][0]).stringValue;
LabelB.text = @(a[index][1]).stringValue;
LabelC.text = @(b).stringValue;
```

Comment: This answer is a nice idea but it won't work because it assumes that the chances are the same for the first two numbers. But the ratio for the 3 and 4 pair is 1 out of 3, not 1 out of 2.